# Swap adjacent elements in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, swap

I am trying to build a method in Ruby that will take in a string that has been split into an array of letters and then iterate through the array, swapping the element at index n with that at index n+1. The method will then join the new array into a string and push it to another array.

Here is an example of what I am looking to do:

```
string = "teh"
some_method(string)
  some ruby magic here
  array << new_string
end
```

Expected output:

```
["eth", "the"]
```

This is for a spell checker program I am writing for school. The method will check if letters in a misspelled word are swapped by checking to see if the output array elements are in the dictionary. If they are, it will return the word with that is most likely the correct word. I haven't had any luck finding articles or documentation on how to build such a method in ruby or on an existing method to do this. I've been tinkering with building this method for awhile now but my code isn't behaving anything like what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Swapping of variables (or array elements for that matter) is trivially done with a temp variable. "but my code isn't behaving anything like what I need" - do you have tests? They can help with this.

Comment: You've given one very tiny example of what you'd want. How would you express "take off last letter and put on front of string" in Ruby?

Comment: @tadman: that would be a very unusual typo :)

Comment: BTW, in ruby you don't even need the temp variable. Use parallel assignment: `arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]`

Comment: I just started learning Ruby so I don't know that much about TDD yet. My test is that the output array includes at least one word that is in the dictionary and is of the same length as the input word. In this case, "the" is in the dictionary, while "eth" isn't.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH There's no excuse for not knowing about tests, they're trivial to write and make getting this correct a lot easier. If you don't know how they work, spend ten minutes learning about them and approach it from that angle. You'll save hours of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Without splitting it into arrays then joining to new arrays (because that doesn't seem necessary):

```
def some_method(string)
  swapped_strings = []
  (0...string.size-1).each do |i|
    temp_string = string.dup
    temp_string[i], temp_string[i+1] = temp_string[i+1], temp_string[i]
    swapped_strings << temp_string
  end
  swapped_strings
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Sergio advised, you want to use parallel assignment for this:

```
def reverse_em(str)
  (0...str.size-1).map do |i|
    s = str.dup
    s[i], s[i+1] = s[i+1], s[i]
    s
  end
end

candidates = reverse_em "alogrithm"
  #=> ["laogrithm", "aolgrithm", "algorithm", "alorgithm",
  #    "alogirthm", "alogrtihm", "alogrihtm", "alogritmh"]

dictionary_check(candidates)
  #=> algorithm
  #   al·go·rithm
  #   noun \ˈal-gə-ˌri-thəm\
  #   a set of steps that are followed in order to solve a
  #   mathematical problem or to complete a computer process
```